# JavaScript split string around emails

Tags: javascript, regex, email

So I have this list of emails:

```
john.doe@doe.com
john.doe@doe.com
john.doe@doe.com
john.doe@doe.com
john.doe@doe.com
john.doe@doe.com
john.doe@doe.com
john.doe@doe.com
```

It comes through as a string, sometimes with a return character at the end of each line, sometimes it doesn't. All I want to be able to do is pull out each email from the string using regex.

So I've got this regex exp from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript):

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

How do I get it to match many email addresses and return me each individual email?

**I do not** want to split on a return character, I can't always garauntee that it will be that character that will split the list up. These emails are pasted in from the users clipboard. If it were that easy, I wouldn't have asked ;)

Comment: And why not just `str.split("\n")` ?

Comment: or replace `"\n"`s with a `;`

Comment: See update for more info

Comment: How about replacing any number of white-spaces with a single white-space of your choice?

Comment: @Terry I have just answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have re work the answer to incorporate what @adeneo said:

```
$scope.pasteThis = function(e) {
    var emails = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

    var emailArray = emails.split(/(\n|\s|,)/);

    angular.forEach(emailArray, function (e) {
        var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;

        if (EMAIL_REGEXP.test(e)) {
            if (!contains($scope.emailAddresses, e)) {
                $scope.emailAddresses.push(e);
            }
        }
    });
}

function contains(arr, el) {
    var found = false;
    angular.forEach(arr, function(e) {
        if (e == el) {
            found = true;
        }
    });

    return found;
}
```

So `EMAIL_REGEXP` is from the Angular source code. I use that in other places so it is very appropriate to use it here (consistency).

This function makes sure that after the emails are split, each one is a valid email address. This means that no mess can get through.

Answer (score 2):

> It comes through as a string, **with a return character** at the end of
>   each line.

Then just split the string on newlines ?

```
var email_array = str.split("\n");
```

Comment: What if it doesn't come through as a return character, what if it is just a space which separates them? I don't know how the email address(es) will come through, that is why I can't just split on `\n` because that wouldn't be safe enough

Comment: Then split on space, newlines, commas and whatever it can be `str.split(/(\n|\s|,)/)` etc.

Comment: Matching emails with a regex is complicated, and you will fail. For instance your regex fails for `.@example.com` which is a valid email etc.

Comment: spaces fails : `Ima Fool@example.com`, special characters will fail : `name@bløff.se`  and a number of others.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a VERY simple way to do it.

`/([^;:<>!?\n]+\@[^;:<>!?\n]+\.[^;:<>!?\n]+)/gmi`

### Explanation:

The `[^;:<>!?\n]` matches everything EXCEPT those characters.  So `[^;:<>!?\n]+` just means match everything but these as many times as needed.

Then match an `@` symbol.

Then match as many of NOT these (`[^;:<>!?\n]`) as needed again.

Then match a literal dot (.).

Then DON'T match these (`[^;:<>!?\n]`) again.

The `gmi`s at the end are called flags.  They mean:

1. `g` means global.  Match this RegEx over and over.
2. `m` means multi-line.  Don't stop at the end of the first line of emails.
3. `i` means insensitive.  Don't worry about the upper and lower cases.

Demonstrations here: https://regex101.com/r/aC5cK2/1

Comment: That sir, is an awesome answer! I will try it out in the new year thanks :)

Comment: @CallumLinington, please accept my answer if it works for you :)  Glad to help!